# Different actual font sizes with the same font's point size in Qt 5

Tags: qt, svg, fonts, qt5, dpi

I use `QGraphicsScene` for drawing some stuff. Look at spinbox in the view.

[image: Spinbox on screen]

Font's point size is 14, let my screen be 96 dpi. Looks ok.

When I export my scene to SVG with `QSvgGenerator`, I set resolution, for example, to 150. In drawing I calculate all with the given dpi and set fonts' sizes with `setPointSize()`, so text should be the same scale as on the screen.

But what I see is:

[image: Spinbox in SVG]

And everywhere where I draw text in SVG, doesn't matter is it a `QPainter::drawText()` or `QTextDocument::drawContents()`, fonts with the same point size actually a little bigger than on screen.

I can't figured out what is wrong. Any ideas?

P.S. A little different sizes of spinboxes is a scaling in PDF viewer. Look at the proportion of text `1`. Font in SVG bigger approximately on 4 pt.

Comment: Sure, I can workaround the problem by decreasing fonts' sizes on ~4 pt when rendering in SVG, but it's no a good idea in my opinion.

Comment: SVG is resolution independent. I am unclear on why you are trying to change the DPI and recalculate all sizes.  Can you explain please?

Comment: Who did tell it to you?

Comment: resolution : int
This property holds the resolution of the generated output
The resolution is specified in dots per inch, and is used to calculate the physical size of an SVG drawing.
This property was introduced in Qt 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

In SVG all is ok. All sizes are correct. Problem is in drawing on the screen, because `QPainter` uses smaller DPI than physical DPI of the screen when drawing text with point size set. I guess that QPainter uses hardcoded DPI somewhere.